# react-hook-form register validate option ignored or not executed

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form

If I go into the typescript definition of `register` from `useForm` in react-hook-form version 7.45.1, it says (I added line breaks for readability):

```
 * @remarks
 * [API](https://react-hook-form.com/docs/useform/register)
   [Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-form-register-ts-ip2j3)
   [Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JFIpCoajYkA)
```

So if I follow the remarks and I go to that code sandbox (which uses the version 7 package although it mentions a V6 template) and modify `App.tsx` to add a `validate` function:

```
  const validate = (value: string) => {
    console.log({value});
    return true;
  }
```

and I put that function in `firstName`'s `register` options:

```
<input {...register("firstName", { validate })} placeholder="First name" />
```

and I type in the first name field, nothing gets logged to the code sandbox simulator's console. **My question is why?** This experience matches what I get in my own code locally with version 7.

As far as I can tell from the [documentation](https://react-hook-form.com/docs/useform/register#options) linked in the remarks above, this is a valid and supported use case and the validate function is supposed to be executed against the contents of the field. Furthermore, the code completion in my editor and in the code sandbox both agree with the documentation. Finally, I delved deep into the `.d.ts` files and it appears that it is indeed supposed to accept validation functions of this form for the `validate` option.

This is what the documentation says verbatim:

> You can pass a callback function as the argument to validate, or you
> can pass an object of callback functions to validate all of them. This
> function will be executed on its own without depending on other
> validation rules included in the required attribute.

```
<input
  {...register("test", {
    validate: (value, formValues) => value === '1'
  })}
/>
```

***So, as above, why is it not executing the validate function?***

Answer (score 0):

The answer is `useForm<FormValues>({ mode: "onChange" });`. This will cause it to validate as you type. I noticed while I was using [someone else's sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-form-regex-validation-test-959oh) to validate patterns. That one validates minimum length you type, but only after submit is hit at least once. It gave me the idea to check the docs regarding whether local field validation was controlled at the whole form level, and it is.